# Relative path for multiple resources directories in the same package, containing SQL for use in scala spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, classpath, relative-path

I have a scala spark package organized with directories for different projects.  Each project can have its own set of SparkSQL queries and I want to organize them in a child directory of each project directory.  For example:

```
src/
src/project1
src/project1/Project1WithMainMethod.scala
src/project1/resources
src/project1/resources/sql_file_1.sql
src/project1/resources/sql_file_2.sql
src/project2
src/project2/Project2WithMainMethod.scala
src/project2/resources
src/project2/resources/sql_file_1.sql
src/project2/resources/sql_file_2.sql
```

The actual sql filenames can be anything.  I want to write a method in either scala or java that returns the file contents as a string, that can be passed into spark.sql(sqlFile) to be used as a dataframe.

For example, given this method spec:

`def getFileAsString(fileName: String): String`

If I call getFileAsString("sql_file_1.sql") from Project1WithMainMethod.scala, it should return the contents of the file from here, as a string: src/project1/resources/sql_file_1.sql

Likewise, if I call getFileAsString("sql_file_1.sql") from Project2WithMainMethod.scala, it should return the contents of the file from here: src/project2/resources/sql_file_1.sql

Or, if I specify the path of a different project and call getFileAsString("project2/resources/sql_file_1.sql") from Project1WithMainMethod.scala, it should return the contents of the file here: src/project2/resources/sql_file_1.sql

I've found at least 5-6 different ways to deal with relative paths, classpaths, resources directories, and none of them seem to fit for my use case.  Most suggest using one "resources" directory for the entire repo.

Maybe my use case is not a good fit for OOP or java, but in my head it seems to work well for data pipelines in spark that serve a common set of customers.  If I can get the SQL files loaded correctly into a string... seems so simple yet I am really struggling to do this efficiently.

Appreciate any help you can offer!

Comment: one question why are you keeping files inside src folder, you can put outside of src directory & access ? because keeping inside src directory & whenever if you want to change any sql file you have to change code & regenerate jar file.

Comment: also can you tell me what are you going to do with those sql files ?

Comment: The sql files will be read into a dataframe using syntax like spark.sql(getFileAsString("sql_file_1.sql")).  Then the dataframes will be used in transformation business logic to generate a final output.  The SparkSQL queries already exist in another system, and will be migrating them to the new package as-is to enable version control and CI/CD.  Building the .jar for the spark application is part of the development workflow.  The SQL is unlikely to change.